# Using regex to validate mask and limit range in currency

Tags: regex

I am working on a feature on my application and now have a requirement that need a regex to validate the mask typed by the user (it is ok) and limit the range typed. For example, if I type:

```
100,00 - can pass
50,00 - can pass
100.000,00 - can pass
100.000,01 - more than 100k not pass
```

Now, I have my regex working to validate the mask, but I can not limit the range...

```
^\$?(([1-9]\d{0,2}(.\d{3})*)|0)?\,\d{1,2}$
```

Anyone knows how can I achieve this limitation?

Comment: Do yourself a favor, convert the strings to floats and compare them programatically. It can be done with regular expressions only but this is not what they were made for and you'll get an expression you're likely to have problems with very soon in the future.

Comment: I have some limitation on our application....I can only validate when user is typing

Comment: Are you using Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to validate the `100.000,00` part separately. Also, remember that `\.` matches a dot, and that in your current regex, you allow an unlimited number of repetitions, so `100.000.000.000,00` currently passes.

Try this:

```
^\$?(?:100\.000,00|(?:[1-9]\d?\.\d{3}|[1-9]\d{0,2}|0)\,\d{1,2})$
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/f33j3x/1).

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # Start of string
\$?                 # Match optional dollar sign
(?:                 # Group: Match either
 100\.000,00        # 100.000,00
|                   # or
 (?:                # Group: Match either
  [1-9]\d?\.\d{3}   # a number between 1.000 and 99.999
 |                  # or
  [1-9]\d{0,2}      # a number between 1 and 999  
 |                  # or
  0                 # 0
 )                  # End of inner group
 \,\d{1,2}          # Match , and one or two digits
)                   # end of outer group
$
```